# Why does Cygwin need _two_ reboots before sshd picks up PATH environment var changes?

Tags: windows, ssh, cygwin, environment

I have a very strange problem with Cygwin sshd and changing the PATH environment variable through the Windows control panel. This is with Windows 10 64 running in a Parallels VM

**After a reboot** ssh sessions into the Windows machine will still use the old path. Local Cygwin sessions have no such problem: they will use the new path.

Note the bold text: I am aware that without the reboot this is expected to happen (because `sshd` got started with the old environment). But the *After the reboot* has got me baffled. If I ssh into the machine I see the old PATH. If I then reboot the VM again and ssh in again I finally see the new path.

Incidentally (fodder for future people googling this) I had the problem while using `gitlab-runner` to run CI/CD jobs on Windows using Parallels VMs on my Mac. So I would prepare the VM to have all the right tools installed and everything set correctly, then shut it down. `gitlab-runner` will then clone the VM and run the CI/CD jobs on it. Works now, as long as I reboot the original VM twice with an ssh session in between before having it cloned by gitlab-runner:-)

Answer (score 1):

I never posted the answer I found: the problem was that hibernate was enabled on Windows. Actually the first "restart" was usually a shutdown followed by a startup.

But, by default Win10 has hibernate enabled, and if that is the case a shutdown and startup don't actually reboot the OS.

Disabling hibernate fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your Cygwin `sshd` installation, as described in "[Installing Cygwin and Starting the SSH Daemon](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24628_01/install.121/e22624/preinstall_req_cygwin_ssh.htm#EMBSC281)"

- it makes sure the `%PATH%` does not reference other SSH, like W10 OpenSSH.
- it stops any other SSH service.
- it defines a Cygwin SSH Windows service, using a local account, which then [should pick up the same account new path](https://serverfault.com/q/292040/783) after a single reboot (or even with restarting the service, without reboot)

[image: Cygwin sshd service]

I am not sure why you need two reboots in your case, but see if that Cygwin sshd setup works better.